# VBA Run-Time Error 1004: Range(“ ”).Formula

Tags: vba, excel

Basically, I would like to change the significant figure of a cell based on the number of significant figure of another cell.

I got a formula that works in worksheet cell, the source of magic formula: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41891803/9111492

And now, I would like to move that formula to vbe so that the formula is insert to a cell when the button is pressed. But I am facing an error.

Here's the code that I had edited and got an

> error 1004

```
Dim NRC As Range
Range(NRC.Offset(-1, 35), NRC.Offset(-1, 38)).Formula = _
        "=TEXT(IF(" & NRC.Offset(-1, 39).Address & "<0,""-"","""")&LEFT(TEXT(ABS(" & NRC.Offset(-1, 39).Address & "),""0.""&REPT(""0""," & NRC.Offset(-1, 41).Address & "-1)&""E+00"")," & NRC.Offset(-1, 41).Address & "+1)*10^FLOOR(LOG10(TEXT(ABS(" & NRC.Offset(-1, 39).Address & "),""0.""&REPT(""0""," & NRC.Offset(-1, 41).Address & "-1)&""E+00"")),1),(""""&(IF(OR(AND(FLOOR(LOG10(TEXT(ABS(" & NRC.Offset(-1, 39).Address & "),""0.""&REPT(""0""," & NRC.Offset(-1, 41).Address & "-1)&""E+00"")),1)+1=" & NRC.Offset(-1, 41).Address & ",RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT(ABS(" & NRC.Offset(-1, 39).Address & "),""0.""&REPT(""0""," & NRC.Offset(-1, 41).Address & "-1)&""E+00"")," & NRC.Offset(-1, 41).Address & "+1)*10^FLOOR(LOG10(TEXT(ABS(" & NRC.Offset(-1, 39).Address & "),""" & _
        "T(""0""," & NRC.Offset(-1, 41).Address & "-1)&""E+00"")),1),1)=""0""),LOG10(TEXT(ABS(" & NRC.Offset(-1, 39).Address & "),""0.""&REPT(""0""," & NRC.Offset(-1, 41).Address & "-1)&""E+00""))<=" & NRC.Offset(-1, 41).Address & "-1),""0."",""#"")&REPT(""0"",IF(" & NRC.Offset(-1, 41).Address & "-1-(FLOOR(LOG10(TEXT(ABS(" & NRC.Offset(-1, 39).Address & "),""0.""&REPT(""0""," & NRC.Offset(-1, 41).Address & "-1)&""E+00"")),1))>0," & NRC.Offset(-1, 41).Address & "-1-(FLOOR(LOG10(TEXT(ABS(" & NRC.Offset(-1, 39).Address & "),""0.""&REPT(""0""," & NRC.Offset(-1, 41).Address & "-1)&""E+00"")),1)),0)))))"
```

NRC is the name for a range

NRC.Offset(-1, 39) is the cell that contain the number that I would like to change the significant number

NRC.Offset(-1, 41) Is the cell that contain the number of significant figure

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Copy** the entire formula from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41891803/8112776) that you are trying to duplicate.  Here's an *exact copy* of it:

`=TEXT(IF(A1<0,"-","")&LEFT(TEXT(ABS(A1),"0."&REPT("0",sigfigs-1)&"E+00"),sigfigs+1)*10^FLOOR(LOG10(TEXT(ABS(A1),"0."&REPT("0",sigfigs-1)&"E+00")),1),(""&(IF(OR(AND(FLOOR(LOG10(TEXT(ABS(A1),"0."&REPT("0",sigfigs-1)&"E+00")),1)+1=sigfigs,RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT(ABS(A1),"0."&REPT("0",sigfigs-1)&"E+00"),sigfigs+1)*10^FLOOR(LOG10(TEXT(ABS(A1),"0."&REPT("0",sigfigs-1)&"E+00")),1),1)="0"),LOG10(TEXT(ABS(A1),"0."&REPT("0",sigfigs-1)&"E+00"))<=sigfigs-1),"0.","#")&REPT("0",IF(sigfigs-1-(FLOOR(LOG10(TEXT(ABS(A1),"0."&REPT("0",sigfigs-1)&"E+00")),1))>0,sigfigs-1-(FLOOR(LOG10(TEXT(ABS(A1),"0."&REPT("0",sigfigs-1)&"E+00")),1)),0)))))`

2. Create a **new workbook** with sample data:

   - `File` → `New` → `Blank Workbook`.  On the new worksheet:
   - enter number `12.345` into cell **`A1`**
   - enter number `6` into cell **`B1`** (and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
3. Create a named cell *sigfigs*:

   - **Right-click** cell `B1`, click `Define Name...`
   - Type **`sigfigs`** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Next, Create a **new VBA module**:  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
5. In the new module, start with the first line:  `Option Explicit` <sub>(which should *always* be used at the top of *every* module you're working in, especially while learning or troubleshooting code.)</sub>
6. Skip a (blank) line and then **start a new sub** like:

   `Sub PrecisionTest()`

   ... and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the VBE will add the `End Sub` line below.
7. **In between** the lines `Sub...` and `End Sub`:  **Paste** the formula into the VBA Editor:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
8. **Replace** each set of quotes with *two* sets of quotes:

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
   - **Find What:** `"`
   - **Replace With:**  `""`
   - Click **`Replace All`**.  (It should say 62 replacements were made.)
   - Click `OK` and click the X to close the `Replace` window.
9. At the *beginning* of the pasted line of code, enter:  **`Range("C1").Formula="`**
10. At the *end* of the pasted line of code, enter one more set of **quotes**:  **`"`** <sub><sup>*(or just click on  different line and it will be added automatically since it's missing from the end.)*</sup></sub>

### Your module should look now like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PrecisionTest()

    Range("C1").Formula = "=TEXT(IF(A1<0,""-"","""")&LEFT(TEXT(ABS(A1),""0.""&REPT(""0"",sigfigs-1)&""E+00""),sigfigs+1)*10^FLOOR(LOG10(TEXT(ABS(A1),""0.""&REPT(""0"",sigfigs-1)&""E+00"")),1),(""""&(IF(OR(AND(FLOOR(LOG10(TEXT(ABS(A1),""0.""&REPT(""0"",sigfigs-1)&""E+00"")),1)+1=sigfigs,RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT(ABS(A1),""0.""&REPT(""0"",sigfigs-1)&""E+00""),sigfigs+1)*10^FLOOR(LOG10(TEXT(ABS(A1),""0.""&REPT(""0"",sigfigs-1)&""E+00"")),1),1)=""0""),LOG10(TEXT(ABS(A1),""0.""&REPT(""0"",sigfigs-1)&""E+00""))<=sigfigs-1),""0."",""#"")&REPT(""0"",IF(sigfigs-1-(FLOOR(LOG10(TEXT(ABS(A1),""0.""&REPT(""0"",sigfigs-1)&""E+00"")),1))>0,sigfigs-1-(FLOOR(LOG10(TEXT(ABS(A1),""0.""&REPT(""0"",sigfigs-1)&""E+00"")),1)),0)))))"

End Sub
```

11. Click somewhere *inside* the sub and execute it by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.  Worksheet cell `C1` will be populated with the formula, the result of which will be a *string*: `12.3450`.

> Copying other people's posted *(working)* code snippets is very common
>   among coders of **all** experience levels, however it's important to
>   first try to copy the code **exactly** to duplicate it.
>
> Only **after** your copy is verified to be working as expected
>   (correct results; no errors) should you begin to add your own
>   modifications as needed.  Make **one small change at a time**,
>   executing the code to test it **after each change** to ensure it's
>   still working... *(especially at the beginning of the VBA learning-curve.)*

Also, Excel cells are referred to with *Letters* (Columns) and *Numbers* (Rows) so there is no position with a negative number like you were trying to do (and you didn't show any code to **declare** NRC as an object, nor to **Set** is as a **Range**, so you weren't using `Offset` properly.

[Here is a link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel) showing syntax and examples of the **`Range`** object, and here is one about the **`Offset`** method.  I'd also recommend that you check out:

- the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  <sub>*and,*</sub>
- [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Not sure if this will help OP or not; I actually remembered my mom in this post lol and so I'll up vote. :) haha

Comment: Thanks --  there's a "communication  disconnect" I cant identify so I gave it my best shot.  (At the least it might help others!)  ...  Your Mom was a coder?  Mine sure wasn't; the Microwave was hard enough to master.

Comment: Nah she was not. But that is the way she would've given me instruction when she wants to be sure that I do something correctly. Sort of "nagging" at me. haha peace! :p

Comment: @ashleedawg Thanks for the detailed explanation and the step by step guide. It works perfectly. Apologies for making so many confusions as I am new to this community and also VBA. I will learn how to be clear in the question and I'll give more details in the post in future. Thanks a lot and have a great day ahead!

Comment: @L42 hope you can comment something that is useful for every person here. And your vote should be based on the quality of the answer, not because you think it remind you of your mom!

Comment: @LieTheng That was for ashlee as a way of praising her efforts in adding a very detailed answer. No harm intended. And when she answered this, she's just beginning her journey in contributing to the community so I kinda welcome her because seriously, she put up a lot of effort in this post. I actually can't comment anything more because she'd covered it all.

Comment: @ashleedawg I hope my comments doesn't imply any harm or misunderstanding in a way. I'll delete all my comments here once you've responded.